# How do I update column data based on multiple conditions in other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
Color   Name    Age   City   Value
Blue    Bob     28    Atl    0
Green   Bob     27    Chi    0
Blue    Sam     28    Atl    0
```

I have the above DF and I want all values to equal 1 if the color is blue, age is 28 and city is Atl.

I tried using df.loc but I got an error that says 'too many indexers'

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
df.loc[(df.Color=='Blue')&(df.Age==28)&(df.City=='Atl'),'Value']=1
df
Out[687]: 
   Color Name  Age City  Value
0   Blue  Bob   28  Atl      1
1  Green  Bob   27  Chi      0
2   Blue  Sam   28  Atl      1
```

Answer (score 1):

For these problems, I usually default to `np.select`, so that I can create complex conditions, and set the outputs in a clear and expandable way.

First, create your conditions (Create as many of these as you want):

```
p1 = df.Color.eq('Blue')
p2 = df.Age.eq(28)
p3 = df.City.eq('Atl')

condition = p1 & p2 & p3
```

Now using `numpy.select`, passing a list of your conditions, a list of your matching outputs, and a default value:

```
df.assign(Value=np.select([condition], [1], df.Value))
```

```
   Color Name  Age City  Value
0   Blue  Bob   28  Atl      1
1  Green  Bob   27  Chi      0
2   Blue  Sam   28  Atl      1
```

If you really only have one condition, you can also use `numpy.where` here:

```
np.where(condition, 1, df.Value)
# array([1, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where` with multiple conditional statements. If you have the original dataframe you can execute the following code

```
import numpy as np
df['value'] = np.where((df['Color'] == 'Blue') & (df['Age'] == 28) & (df['City'] == 'Atl'), 1, 0)
```

to yield

```
Color  Name  Age  City  Value
Blue   Bob   28   Atl     1
Green  Bob   27   Chi     0
Blue   Sam   28   Atl     1
```

Obviously, you can change the conditions as needed/wanted or even create additional columns using the same technique.